# SSIS 2016 : What kind of connector do we have as a replacement for SharePoint list adapter

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, sharepoint, ssis, odata

We have SharePoint list adapters used in older version of SSIS to get data in & out of sharepoint/SQL Server. In SQL Server 2016 we have OData (Connection Manager for OData) for accessing sharepoint, but I can see OData only available for Source, is there a OData component available for sharepoint target as well?

Any suggestion on how we can use sharepoint as both source & target in SSIS 2016 will be helpful.

Thanks,
Sathesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint List Adapter is up and running. And now even better -> the project was migrated to GitHub and supports SQL 2017.

Please download the latest release via
https://github.com/fan130/mssql-ssis-community-samples/releases